# How to improve this Java regex?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have three formats of text:

1. Dan 3:52-56
2. Acts 6:8-10, 7:54-59
3. 2 Sam 15:13-30, 16:5-13

Ideally, I want to be able to extract all the *groups* e.g. Dan, 3, 52 and 56 in any of the cases and I currently have:

```
/(\S*)\s(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*)($|,\s(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*))/gmix
```

..which works, but doesn't capture the second case very well. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I had a pattern matching problem once, so I decided to use regular expressions. After that I had two pattern matching problems...

Comment: Just got `/(\d*\s*?\w*)\s(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*)($|,\s(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*))/mix` which works for all cases, but I'm thinking there may be a way to improve this.

Comment: I'd consider not using a regex here and going with procedural, commented code.  You're definitely in the write only code area-  it will be next to impossible for your successor to maintain it.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll are you saying Regex may not be efficient for this particular scenario?

Comment: Hmmm I was actually trying to improve the previous code @GabeSechan

Comment: @CrowdStar I understand that.  But regexes are a tricky beast.  If you know them well, you can do an awful lot with them-  but if you were given a snippet of code with that regex how long would it take for you to figure out what it does?  Would you be able to easily edit it?  Now imagine someone who may use a non-trivial regex once a year or so- would he be able to?  At the very least be sure to comment what the different parts of that regex are meant to capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: `((?:\d*\s)?(?:\S*))\s(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*)(?:,\s(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*))?` or, as a java string: `"((?:\\d*\\s)?(?:\\S*))\\s(\\d*):(\\d*)-(\\d*)(?:,\\s(\\d*):(\\d*)-(\\d*))?"`

Ok just edited so '2 Sam' will be in the same group

**Note:** the best way to do this however is to know the exact specification of each element in the input string (if possible) instead of making it work with just 3 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
([\w ]+) (?:(?:(\d+?):(\d+?)\-(\d+))(?:, )?)*
```

with just the `/g` (global) modifier?

Here's a regex101 with an explanation: https://regex101.com/r/pP5pY3/1

Comment: Thanks, only problem is '2 Sam' is meant to be captured together.